# MySql 5.6: Ignores innodb_page_size setting in my.ini

Tags: mysql, innodb

So I tried to increase the innodb_page_size to 32k, by setting this value in my.ini:

```
innodb_page_size=32k
```

I then stopped the MySql service, and restarted it. The service in Win looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56
```

And I edited the correct file, and it's saved:

[image]

but when I look at the variable in [HeidiSql](https://www.heidisql.com/), I see the standard value of 16k:

[image]

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Cross-posting of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214188/mysql-5-6-ignores-innodb-page-size-setting-in-my-ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size says:

> You can specify page size using the values 16k (the default), 8k, or
>   4k. Alternatively, you can specify page size in bytes (4096, 8192,
>   16384).

This means 32k is not supported in MySQL 5.6.

> innodb_page_size can only be configured prior to initializing the
>   MySQL instance and cannot be changed afterward.

This means you can't change the page size, without dropping all InnoDB tablespaces.

Comment: I thought "initializing the MySQL instance" means it needs to be shut down, changed and then started again. If I read on MySql webpage, it indicates that 32k does work, and even 64k: `The maximum row length, except for variable-length columns (VARBINARY, VARCHAR, BLOB and TEXT), is slightly less than half of a page for 4KB, 8KB, 16KB, and 32KB page sizes. For example, the maximum row length for the default innodb_page_size of 16KB is about 8000 bytes. For an InnoDB page size of 64KB, the maximum row length is about 16000 bytes.`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: Yes, initializing the MySQL instance requires a shutdown. You can't change the page size without wiping out all your tablespaces and starting fresh. Make sure you make a mysqldump of data you don't want to lose.

Comment: Also, you're reading about support for 32KB pages in the MySQL 8.0 manual. You said you're using MySQL 5.6, which doesn't have support for that page size. [Support for 32k and 64k page sizes was added in MySQL 5.7.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size)